Why do these blocks of code not all work?
code #1 this code works
 (define *o
  (lambda (x y z)
    (if (= y 0)                                       
        z
        (*o x (sub1 y) (+ z x)))))

(*o 7 3 0)

code#2 this code doesn't work
(define *o (x y z)
    (cond
      ((0? y) z) 
      (else *o x (sub1 y) (+ z x))))                     

(print (*o 7 3 0))
(define *o
  (lambda (x y z)
    (cond
      ((0? y) z) 
      (else *o x (sub1 y) (+ z x))))) 

(*o 7 3 0)

code#3 this code doesn't work
(define *o (x y z)
    (cond
      ((0? y) z) 
      (else *o x (sub1 y) (+ z x))))                     

(print (*o 7 3 0))

#2 tried to use (cond instead of  (if
#3 tried to rephrase the code, omitting the (lambda

You need to study the fundamentals of syntax in more detail. For instance, (*o x (sub1 y) (+ z x)) is one expression, but *o x (sub1 y) (+ z x) is four.

Your define syntax is also wrong in your second and third code blocks. It looks like you're thinking it's the same form as Common Lisp's defun...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'll rewrite your second example to if so you see what is done:
(define *o (x y z)
  (if (0? y)         ; I'm guessing this is like (zero? y)
      z              ; consequent is to return z
      (begin         ; the alternative consiste of 4 expressions
        *o           ; evaluates to a procedure, then thrown away
        x            ; evaluates to a number, then thrown away
        (sub1 y)     ; evaluates to a number, then thrown away 
        (+ z x))))   ; tail expression evaluates to a number and returned 

(*o 1 2 3) ; ==> 4, due to (+ z x)
(*o 1 0 3) ; ==> 3, due to z

The intent probably is to call *0, however you need to use parenthesis to apply it:
(define *o (x y z)
  (if (0? y)                    ; I'm guessing this is like (zero? y)
      z                         ; consequent is to return z
      (*o x (sub1 y) (+ z x)))) ; tail recursive call

with cond:
(define *o (x y z)
    (cond
      ((0? y) z) 
      (else (*o x (sub1 y) (+ z x)))))   

